# String Set being passed in as multiple parameters PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure which takes 3 parameters (1 IN, 2 OUT) through PHP. I pass the following string set `"1,2,3,4"` to PHP from JavaScript using :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

From PHP I get the string and call it like this (after making all proper SQL connections etc):

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2($q, @eset, @leng)");
```

The error I get is `Invalid query: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE fall12018.mst2; expected 3, got 6`

If I remove @eset and @leng I still get the error but with 4 instead of 6, it seems that the procedure is reading in each comma separated member as a separate input, does anybody know how to send the entire set as a single argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like right now your call looks like this (6 params, due to the commas in the value of `$q`):

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2(1,2,3,4, @eset, @leng)");
```

Try encasing $q in quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2('{$q}', @eset, @leng)");
```

Which will result in this (3 params):

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2('1,2,3,4', @eset, @leng)");
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know how I could store the results from the called procedure into PHP variables (ex./ `$eset= SELECT @eset; $length= SELECT @leng;`)?

Comment: You can do something like `$result = mysqli_query("DECLARE @eset INT, @leng INT; CALL mst2('1,2,3,4', @eset, @leng); SELECDT @eset AS a, @leng AS b;");`